# Emv question: link different token with “person”

Tags: applepay, google-pay, emv, mastercard

As I know every time when user add the same card to ApplePay/GooglePay it’s create a new token. When I read payment data over nfc is it have any tag to identify user? It’ mean any constant data for any token which link to physical card? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is Payment Account Reference for this purpose. There are some limitations of its availability and ability to link to original card, so it's really a complex topic that cannot be limited to card-terminal interface, but involve other systems as well.

I'd advise that you discuss this with payment schemes.

Comment: yes, i get PAR when user use phone/clock to pay, but there no PAR when made pay with card

Comment: @user1786639 That's one of the limitations. You will most likely not get it on this interface for physical card.

Comment: and how to link par with physical card?… can be not pan, any identifiers

Comment: As suggested already - please talk to payment schemes. If this is legitimate business, you won't have issues getting some real advice. Stack overflow is not the place to get it and you should not consider any advice received here as reliable enough to spend money or base a consumer-facing solution on it.